# Ejercicio sobre tablas

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje C++ de forma autodidacta y tengo un ejercicio en el cual ya llevo 2 días que no puedo solucionarlo, espero me puedan ayudar a solucionarlo.

El problema es el siguiente: cambia la zona comentada con "rellenar", solamente, para producir las siguiente salida:

```
---*-**-***-****-*****-******-*******---
```

```
int main() {
   bool R[40];
   // rellenar
   for (int k = 0; k < 40; k++) {
      R[k] = (k >= 20);
   }
   // mostrar
   for (int k = 0; k < 40; k++) {
      if (R[k]) cout << '*';
      else cout << '-';
   }
}
```

Como referencia, el ejercicio ha sido copiado de: http://www.minidosis.org/#/actividades/Cpp.Tablas.AsteriscosYGuiones.prob (pero todo el enunciado se ha reproducido en la pregunta)

Comment: No tengo acceso a minidosis.com

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster a mi si que me deja, sería algún problema de public a private?

Comment: @Capt.Teach a mi no me deja porque desde el lugar que conecto esa página está prohibida por proxy, pero eso es lo de menos: cualquier cosa relevante para la pregunta tiene que estar en la pregunta, no en fuentes externas.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster El enlace no aporta más a lo que ya puso en la pregunta. Se trata de cambiar el primer bucle for, para que el segundo bucle for imprima la secuencia dada

Comment: @abulafia No se si el enlace aporta mucho, poco o nada porque no puedo acceder al enlace. Si el contenido del enlace es relevante para la pregunta: debería estar en la pregunta no en una fuente externa. Si el contenido del enlace no es relevante para la pregunta: debe ser borrado.

Comment: Y cuál es el problema con tu código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El patrón con que debes rellenar el array `R` se observa que es:

- Todo `false` excepto ciertas secuencias de `true`.
- La primera secuencia contiene un `true` y se inicia en el índice 3
- La siguiente secuencia contiene dos `true` y se inicia una posición más allá de donde terminó la anterior
- Y así sucesivamente hasta completar una secuencia de 7 `true`

Ya que la secuencia de `true` va creciendo en longitud, necesitarás dos bucles anidados. Uno para ver qué secuencia toca (la de 1, 2, 3... o 7 `true`) y otro para generar cada elemento de esa secuencia.

Te dejo pensarlo un poco más y si lo necesitas puedo darte una posible solución, aunque hay varias formas de hacerlo.

### Edición

Como veo que ya te han dado el código en una respuesta, te publico el mío también, para que veas otros enfoques y preguntes si tienes alguna duda. Observa cómo he usado la sintaxis coma en los bucles, la cual no es muy usual, pues dificulta la lectura y comprensión del código, pero en este caso ayuda a hacerlo más compacto.

```
int main() {
   bool R[40];
   // rellenar. Primero todo con False
   for (int j=0; j < 40; j++) {
       R[j] = false;
   }
   // Ahora solo algunos con True
   for (int N=0, j=2; N<8; N++) {
       for (int i=0; i<N; i++, j++) {
           R[j] = true;
       }
       j++;
   }

   // mostrar
   for (int k = 0; k < 40; k++) {
      if (R[k]) cout << '*';
      else cout << '-';
   }
}
```

Comment: Te agradezco, la informacion adicional donde me diste los puntos para poder resolver el problema por mi cuenta, sin embargo de las dos soluciones aprendi algo. me gusto mas tu respuesta por el echo de a ver respetado  la parte comentada con rellenar que especificaba que solo esa parte tenia que ser llenada y no declaraste ninguna variable  fuera de la zona comentada. estudiare tu respuesta para implementarla por mi cuenta. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
```

int main()
{

```
bool R[40];
int y, cont;
y = 0;
cont = 1;
// rellenar
for (int k = 0; k < 40; k++) {
    if (k < 3 || k>36)
    {
        R[k] = false;
    }
    else
    {
        while (y < cont)
        {
            R[k] = true;
            k++;
            y++;
        }
        R[k] = false;
        cont++;
        y = 0;
    }
}
// mostrar
for (int k = 0; k < 40; k++) {
    if (R[k]) std::cout << '*';
    else std::cout << '-';
}
```

}

Comment: En general se pide que las respuestas no sean solo códigos y que además vengan acompañadas de una explicación, indicando lo que hiciste para solucionar el problema

Comment: Se agradece tu comentario, me ayudo bastante